# Trying to pull text from text area in jsp, returning null

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to change text from a text area on a webpage from my jsp so then I can grab the changed text and then push it to a website using an API. But every time I try to use the .getParameter("textArea") call in my doPost method to get the changed text from the text area, it just prints null when I try to print it out in the console. I have a GET method that gets the information I want from the website and then puts the value of the info in a text area. I have also tested my post method and it does post to the website.

Here is my Controller.java class that has my doGet and doPost methods:

```
package com.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import com.gurock.testrail.APIClient;
import com.gurock.testrail.APIException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/Controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static String local;   //String used to set attribute
//constructor
public Controller() {
    super();
}

// *** doGet method ***

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String input = "";
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) { 
    if(request.getParameter("submitGet") != null) {
    input = request.getParameter("input");
    APIClient client = new APIClient("...");    
    client.setUser("...");          //set user name for login
    client.setPassword("...");             //set password for login
    try {
    JSONObject  c = (JSONObject) client.sendGet("get_case/" + input);    //send a get request to the web page and get case ID
    local = c.get("custom_test_script").toString();                      //get the custom test script from web page
    request.setAttribute("Local", local); //set the attribute of the test script with String local     
  }//try 
    catch (APIException e) {    //Pulls from APIException java class
    e.printStackTrace();
 }//catch
}//if

    //next two lines allows information that was output to stay on the same web page and not redirect too another page and allow more input
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/testCases.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);                                           
}//try
}//doGet


// *** doPost Method ***

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {  //get input from web page 
    if(request.getParameter("submitPost") != null) {
    String test_id=request.getParameter("test_id");
    String textarea = request.getParameter("textArea");
    APIClient client = new APIClient("...");    
    client.setUser("...");          //set user name for login
    client.setPassword("...");            // set password for login
    try { 
    Map data = new HashMap();
    System.out.println(textarea);
    data.put("custom_test_script", textarea);
    client.sendPost("update_case/" + test_id, data);
    }//try
   catch (APIException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}//catch
 }//if
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/testCases.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response); 
}//try
}//doPost
}//Controller
```

Here is my .jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testCases.css">
<title>Test Cases</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Test Cases</h1></center>
<form action="Controller" method="get" id="getForm">

    <label>Input Test Case ID #: </label>
    <input type="text" name="input" value="">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitGet" class="btn btn-
 primary"> <br><br><br><br>
    <label>Test Case Test Script: </label>
    <textarea name="textArea" id="output"> 
 <%=request.getAttribute("Local")%></textarea>
 </form>

 <form action="Controller" method="post" id="postForm">

 <label>Enter Test ID: </label>
 <input type="text" name="test_id" value="">

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitPost" class="btn btn-
primary">

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I think its either an issue with my doPost method or the getParameter() call is trying to get the parameter of the text area before it has text in it. I've tried getAttribute("textArea") as well and it didn't work either. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't your form action be `<form action="Controller" method="post" id="getForm">` changed `method=get` to `method=post` ?

Comment: when i change the method from get to post the information that I try to pull from the website does appear in the text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: All I had to do was move my text area from my get method to my post method in jsp and it worked.

```
<center><h1>Test Cases</h1></center>
<form action="Controller" method="get" id="getForm">

    <label>Input Test Case ID #: </label>
    <input type="text" name="input" value="">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitGet" class="btn btn-
primary"> <br><br><br><br>
</form>

<form action="Controller" method="post" id="postForm">
<label>Test Case Test Script: </label>
    <textarea name="textArea" id="output"> 
<%=request.getAttribute("Local")%></textarea>

<label>Enter Test ID: </label>
 <input type="text" name="test_id" value="">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitPost" class="btn btn-
 primary">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```